# Delayed log-on into windows under domain controller

Tags: windows, authentication, logging, ldap

I`m trying to make the reservation system at school where all computers (windows) runs under domain. Users can book the computer to use. They logs into reservation system via credentials in AD, the task is to automatically unlock the certain computer when the reservation time is reached. Does anybody knows is that possible at all?

Comment: This might be of help: http://superuser.com/questions/328739/how-to-delay-windows-7-autologon-so-that-the-domain-will-be-available